# DirectoryEntry Invoke method name required for getting Authorization Groups

Tags: c#, active-directory, usergroups

I am using the below method of DirectoryEntry

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2

I am trying to fetch the AuthorizationGroups using the invoke method. 
I used the below method

```
          object obGroups = de.Invoke("Groups");
                            foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
                            {
                                // name of group
                                obGpEntry.Name;
                            }
```

But this will not return all active directory groups. I need to get all Authorization Groups the user belongs to

Any idea which is the method name needs to be used for that

Answer (score 0):

Using `.Invoke("Groups")` calls the Windows native [`IADSUser::Groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-groups) method. It only gets the direct membership (not nested groups) and does not give you the primary group. I'm not entirely sure where it's getting that information from, so I couldn't say for certain what it does and doesn't give you.

Are you trying to find the groups for the *current* user (the user currently logged in)? Because there are other ways to do it that let you read the groups from the authentication token. In both ASP.NET and a desktop app you can use [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroup()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups).

But otherwise, you *could* use the [`tokenGroups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-tokengroups) attribute, which gives you all nested security groups for the purposes of authorization:

```
de.RefreshCache(new [] {"tokenGroups"});
var groups = de.Properties["tokenGroups"];
```

However that gives you the SID of the groups, which may not be immediately helpful if you want the names.

There are a few ways to tackle getting all of a user's groups, which depends on how much information you're after and your environment. I wrote an article about this very thing with several sample methods: [Active Directory: Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html)